# gulp-sass includePaths parameter and import of partial files declarations that are not in the main.scss issue

Tags: inheritance, module, sass, gulp, partials

I have a Gulp front-end workflow that uses gulp-sass to process my style sources. I also use Bower to get vendors like Foundation 6 for Sites which I love working with.

Here's what my file organisation looks like:

```
|_ src
  |_ vendor // Custom name for "bower_components"
    |_ foundation-sites
      |_ scss
        |_ grid
          |_ _classes.scss
          |_ _column.scss
          |_ _flex-grid.scss
          |_ _grid.scss
          |_ _gutter.scss
          |_ _layout.scss
          |_ _position.scss
          |_ _row.scss
          |_ _size.scss
        |_ settings
          |_ _settings.scss
  |_ style // Custom styles
    |_ vendor-override // Modifications made on copied/pasted sources from vendors; file organisation and names stay the same. 
      |_ foundation-sites
        |_ scss
          |_ grid
            |_ _flex-grid.scss
          |_ settings
            |_ _settings.scss        
    |_ mais.scss
  |_ gulpfile.js
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, when available, to get my `vendor-override` files automatically replacing the original `vendor` files when compiling.

Here's what my (simplified and focused on the SASS task) `gulpfile.js` looks like ([full Front-End development workflow using NPM, Bower and Gulp available here on GitHub](https://github.com/franklang/change36x-starter-theme/tree/base-workflow)) :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('src/style/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: ['src/style/', 'src/style/vendor-override/foundation-sites/scss/', 'src/vendor/foundation-sites/scss/']
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('style/'));
});
```

Please note that in order to avoid declaring complicated `@import` paths to either the vendor or the vendor overwrite sources, I use the `includePaths` parameter of the gulp-sass plugin (see above).

Here's how complicated `@import` paths would look like in my `main.scss` file:

```
// Settings
// import your own `settings` here or
// import and modify the default settings through
// @import 'settings/settings';
@import 'vendor-override/foundation-sites/scss/settings/settings';

// Components
@import '../vendor/foundation-sites/scss/grid/grid';
[...]
@include foundation-flex-grid;
```

And here's how my `main.scss` actually looks like (paths are the orginal paths form the `foundation.scss` vendor file) - thanks to gulp-sass `includePaths` parameter :

```
// Settings
// import your own `settings` here or
// import and modify the default settings through
@import 'settings/settings';

// Components
@import 'grid/grid';

[...]
@include foundation-flex-grid;
```

So far, gulp-sass `includePaths` parameter works like a charm with my overwrite of `foundation-sites/scss/settings/_settings.scss`.

But it fails compiling my overwrite of `foundation-sites/scss/grid/_flex-grid.scss`. And this is probably because `_flex.grid.scss` is a partial imported from `_grid.scss` (Foundation's SASS Grid module).

Here's what `foundation-sites/scss/grid/_grid.scss` looks like (from Foundation's vendor source) :

```
@import 'row';
@import 'column';
@import 'size';
@import 'position';
@import 'gutter';
@import 'classes';
@import 'layout';

@import 'flex-grid';
```

As long as an `@import` is done from the `main.scss` file, it works.
Once an `@import` is done from a sub file, it doesn't work anymore.

Any idea if what I want to achieve is even possible and you should I proceed ?
Many thanks !